# Single quote missing in query

Tags: java, mysql

i am passing date in sql query using java.Below is my code that retrieve no result.

```
java.sql.Date d1=java.sql.Date.valueOf(startDate);
        java.sql.Date d2=java.sql.Date.valueOf(enddate); 
        String url= "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+serverName+"/"+database;;
        String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("Connected to the database!!! Getting table list...");

            Statement sta = conn.createStatement();


            String Sql = "Select INDEX from Table where DATE between "+d1+" and "+d2;
            System.out.println("sql="+Sql);
             rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}
```

Query returns no row because date should be passed as '2015-02-28' but query treats date as 2015-02-28 without single quote.Please suggest.

Comment: `between '"+d1+"' and '"+d2+"'"`

Comment: Use prepared statements. The sql statement do not know that your `d1`and`d2` are dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add single quotes

```
String Sql = "Select INDEX from Table where DATE between '"+d1+"' and '"+d2+"'";
```

but the best option would be using PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 1):

Creating SQL statements by concatenating strings together makes your software vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (if the values of the variables come from user input).

You should use `PreparedStatement` instead:

```
PreparedStatement sta =
    conn.prepareStatement("Select INDEX from Table where DATE between ? and ?");

sta.setDate(1, d1);
sta.setDate(2, d2);

rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like so:

```
String Sql = "Select INDEX from Table where DATE between '"+d1+"' and '"+d2 + "'";
```

That being said, you should look into [`PreparedStatements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues in the query

1. `INDEX` is a reserved word and you need to escape it using backticks http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html
2. Date should be used within quotes

So the query should be

```
String Sql = "Select `INDEX` from Table where DATE between '"+d1+"' and '"+d2+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your Query with

```
String Sql = "Select INDEX from Table where DATE between '"+d1+"' and '"+d2+"'";
```

I suggest you to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) Instead

```
String query="Select INDEX from Table where DATE between ? and ?";
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setDate(1,d1);
ps.setDate(2,d2);
ps.executeQuery();
```